# Prevent rpm upgrade from very old version

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have an rpm package `pkg` which is now at the latest version (say 10). I want to create `pkg-10.rpm` which will upgrade `pkg` installed on the system only if its version is 5 or greater. Upgrade from versions older than 5 should no longer be supported. I tried to add `Conflicts: pkg < 5` to the spec file. But `rpm -Uvh pkg-10.rpm` upgrades the package even when an older version (say 2) of the package is installed. Is there a way to achieve this without renaming the package ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method (I know of), in-built in `rpm`. The only workaround I can think of is managing different repositories (if you publish your packages in your own repositories). For example one **legacy** and one **update** repository.

The **legacy** repository containing only some updates for your older systems with pkg < 5,
The **update** repository with all updates.

You could then select on each machine which repositories you update from.

Answer (score 0):

RPM doesn't support this built-in. You'd have to write some kind of detection script and then in your `%pre` scriptlet abort if you find a version that is too old (by checking the configuration file or something like that).